# Почему нельзя обратиться через точку к свойству объекта?

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

У меня есть сервис, который возвращает объект с датами:

```
@Injectable()
export class DateService {

  constructor() { }

  getNowDate(): Object {
    let d = new Date();
    d.setHours(d.getHours() + 3);
    let dateHuman = d.toISOString();
    let unixTimeStamp = Math.floor(d.getTime() / 1000) - (60 * 60 * 3);     

    return {
        dateHuman: dateHuman,
        unixTimeStamp: unixTimeStamp
    };
  };
}
```

Я его использую в компоненте так:

```
import { DateService } from '../services/date.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-question',
  templateUrl: './question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question.component.scss']
})
export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dateService: DateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.dateService.getNowDate()['dateHuman']);
  }
}
```

Всё ок - дата выводится. Но если я пытаюсь выводить дату так:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.dateService.getNowDate().dateHuman);
  }
```

То получаю следующую ошибку:

> Property 'dateHuman' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Объясните пожалуйста в чём причина этого явления, почему в данном случае обращение к свойству через точку и через скобку не равноценны?

Comment: а что в тексте: _Property 'dateHuman' does not exist on type 'Object'._ не ясно?

Comment: Вот это как раз и непонятно. я же возвращаю это свойство явно:     return {
     dateHuman: dateHuman,
     unixTimeStamp: unixTimeStamp
    };

Comment: неважно что ты возвращаешь, важно какой тип ты указал при этом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в проверке компилятором:

при обращении через точку, компилятор проверяет, есть ли указанное свойство в **типе** или нет

при обращении через скобки - не проверяет.

---

В примере в вопросе: метод `getNowDate` возвращает объект типа `Object`, в этом ***типе*** **нет** свойства `dateHuman`, поэтому при проверке компилятор выбрасывает указанную ошибку.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что, указав в конструкторе private dateService: DateService, я объявил тип private DateService? Но откуда компилятор знает что это за тип(какие свойства в нём есть)? И можно ли его изменить?

Comment: @cyklop77m нет не правильно. В **конструкторе** ты объявляешь **поле класса** с типом `DateService`. Компилятор знает об этом типе, так как ты сам указал про него все, добавив строчку `import { DateService } from '../services/date.service';`

Answer (score 2):

Проблема - вот в этой строчке:

```
getNowDate(): Object
```

Здесь вы объявляете, что метод `getNowDate` возвращает `Object` - а у типа `Object` нет свойства `dateHuman`.

Уберите явное указание типа возвращаемого значения у метода чтобы позволить компилятору самому вывести его из оператора `return`.

Альтернативный вариант - объявите интерфейс, который будет возвращать ваш метод:

```
interface IDateInfo {
    dateHuman: string;
    unixTimeStamp: number;
}

getNowDate(): IDateInfo
```